# Xamarin.Forms Notification Service for Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm relatively new to Android app development and Xamarin.Forms development in general, so I'm looking for an advice on what is the best way to implement the following: 
When active, my app downloads data using a simple REST appi service (I'm using a HttpClient for this). Now what I want is when the app is closed, to still check if some data is changed on the server, using the same method as it was used when the app is running, and if so, to fire up the notification to the user.
I've been reading about the services, and that seems like a solution to my problems, but what I need to know is: what kind of service is most suitable for this task? Is it a Bound service, Intent service or Started service? Or is there  a way to achieve this without the use of the service?

Comment: Instead of verifying from data changes from the App why don't you better notify the user from the server whenever a change occurs? You can do that with a push notification. You can then refresh your data in the background with a background service before the notification is presented to the user.

Comment: I did consider that solution, but the problem is that I don't have the access to the server side of the application

Answer (score 0):

azure notification hubs sends to apple and google play

Comment: That doesn't work for me because I don't have an access to the server side.